# IborIborBasisSwapRateHelper and OvernightIborBasisSwapRateHelper in QuantLib

Tags: quantlib

I am running QuantLib (v1.26) in python and I notice that there are now rate helpers for Libor basis swaps (IborIborBasisSwapRateHelper) and OIS basis swaps (OvernightIborBasisSwapRateHelper). However, I cant find any documentation for them.

Any guidance on how to use these for bootstrapping would be much appreciated. Particularly for the OvernightIborBasisSwapRateHelper as I am not sure how to simultaneously bootstrap the OIS curve used for discounting (which will need a projection curve) and the IRS curve (which will need an OIS curve)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no documentation, but you can see examples of their usage in the test suite at https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/blob/master/test-suite/basisswapratehelpers.cpp.

The two curves are not bootstrapped simultaneously; the idea is that you'll bootstrap one of them first, using other helpers, and then use it to bootstrap the other.  For instance, you could bootstrap the OIS curve using OIS quotes and `OISRateHelper`, and then use it to bootstrap the swap curve using `OvernightIborBasisSwapRateHelper`.